# Multiplying the matrix via its transpose using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to multiply X by its transpose:

[image]

I am bit puzzled by the fact that `X` is an `np.array` of `list`'s.

Comment: Because the second element has size of 5 while others have size of 4

Comment: @Psidom Wow. I have missed that. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

o turn a list of list on python into array and to be able to use arithmetic calculations on it after you can use :

```
import numpy as np
A = [[638, 331, 327, 30.3],
     [331,589,384,560], #0.049
     [327,384,560,4.81],
     [3.03,0.049,4.81,1.46]]
X = np.array([np.array(a) for a in A])
```

because in your code if you check well the type of X [i] it'll be a list and so we can not make calcluls on.

a second remark. Your matrix X has 4 lines and 4 columns but however the 2nd line contains 5 element when the rest lines contains 4 elements ( i put in comment the additional element)

So now that you have an array matrix of 4x4 you can use :

```
np.dot(X,X.T)
```